# What happens when all the datanodes fail in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I read from hadoop operations that if a datanode fails during writing process,

> A new replication pipeline containing the remaining datanodes is
>   opened and the write resumes. At this point, things are mostly back to
>   normal and the write operation continues until the file is closed. The
>   namenode will notice that one of the blocks in the file is
>   under-replicated and will arrange for a new replica to be created
>   asynchronously. A client can recover from multiple failed datanodes
>   provided at least a minimum number of replicas are written (by
>   default, this is one).

But what happens if all the datanodes fail? i.e., minimum number of replicas are not written?
Will client ask namenode to give new list of datanodes? or will the job fail?

**Note** :  My question is NOT what happens when all the data nodes fails in the cluster. Question is what happens if all the datanodes to which the client was supposed to write, fails, **during the write operation**

Suppose namenode told the client to write BLOCK B1 to datanodes D1 in Rack1, D2 in Rack2 and D3 in Rack1. There might be other racks also in the cluster(Rack 4,5,6,...). If Rack1 and 2 failed during the write process, client knows that the data was not written successfully since it didn't receive the ACK from the datanodes, At this point, will it ask Namenode to give new set of datanodes? may be in the still alive Racks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got what you are asking. DFSClient will get a list of datanodes from the namenode where it is supposed to write a block (say A) of a file. DFSClient will iterate over that list of Datanodes and write the block A in those locations. If block write fails in the first datanodes, it'll abandon the block write and ask namenode a new set of datanodes where it can attempt to write again.

Here the sample code from DFSClient that explains that -

```
private DatanodeInfo[] nextBlockOutputStream(String client) throws IOException {
    //----- other code ------
    do {
            hasError = false;
            lastException = null;
            errorIndex = 0;
            retry = false;
            nodes = null;
            success = false;

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            lb = locateFollowingBlock(startTime);
            block = lb.getBlock();
            accessToken = lb.getBlockToken();
            nodes = lb.getLocations();

            //
            // Connect to first DataNode in the list.
            //
            success = createBlockOutputStream(nodes, clientName, false);

            if (!success) {
              LOG.info("Abandoning block " + block);
              namenode.abandonBlock(block, src, clientName);

              // Connection failed.  Let's wait a little bit and retry
              retry = true;
              try {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > 5000) {
                  LOG.info("Waiting to find target node: " + nodes[0].getName());
                }
                Thread.sleep(6000);
              } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
              }
            }
          } while (retry && --count >= 0);

          if (!success) {
            throw new IOException("Unable to create new block.");
          }
     return nodes;
}
```

Comment: thanx for the reply. I understand that the data will be lost if all the datanodes fail and that it is very rare case also. I am sorry may be my question was not clear so I have added a note to the question.

Comment: am sorry but i couldnt find the answer to my question

Comment: Which part you didn't get or I understood your question wrong? I'm really curious? I think it'll help me too! Thanks

Comment: client C1 is writing block B1 to data node D1. D2 and D3 are in queue. while doing the writing on D1, nodes D1,D2 and D3 failed. now none of the data nodes to which C1 was supposed to write is alive. At this point what will happen? Will C1 try to get new list of data nodes (may be D4,D5,D6) from the namenode?

Comment: one more question, what happens if the block B1 is corrupted in all the datanodes? i.e., if checksum is incorrect. Thanx